# Mongo - Update nested array of objects by _id

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

How can I access an array of object with their own _id and update it with Mongo/Mongoose?

Take a look to my update query and check if there's something wrong, because this code doesn't return any error, but it doesn't really update the field

```
modelUser.findOneAndUpdate(
  { userName: body.author, "portfolio._id": body.id },
  { new: true },
  {
    $set: {  //I thing the problem it's over here
      "portfolio.$.profitLoss": profitLoss,
      "portfolio.$.percentage": percentage
    }
  },
  (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(`Done`);
  }
);
```

This is my User Schema:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  ...stuff,
  portfolio: [
    {
      coin: String,
      amount: String,
      price: String,
      bought: Date,
      profitLoss: String,
      percentage: String
    }
  ],
});
```

Basically i think mongo just don't know which of these sub documents should update, I don't know if there's something like another `findOneAndUpdate` for sub object/document by id.

Comment: In the schema portfolia doesn't have the _id field. If you add id field the query should work.

Comment: @SergiNadal If you don't specify what an _id is, add it by defaults and creates itself? or I'm wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure, I think not! You can check it very easy,in the mongo shell just find a document and explore it and you'll see if the array has an _id field. 
I usually use Roto 3T, to search in the mongo collection, https://robomongo.org/

Answer (score 0):

Just changed `findOneAndUpdate` to `updateOne` and everything works.